# How to search in fields delimited by the tilde character

Tags: sql-server, tilde-expansion

I have a field in the database separated by tilde `~`

I can't figure out how to search in the field with a mssql query.

Ex `select * from table where john in repnames`

Data is in the field like `tom~john~max`

I've tried a few searches on Google but haven't found any tips.

Comment: Is the goal to break out the names from the tilde delimited list? You could, as Kin suggested do a like although you should do like '%John%'. However, that approach has a logical hole IF the names are not unique, i.e. Jon would match ~Jonathon~

Comment: I think just using the good old like '%xxx%' is going to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
select column1, column2
from table
where repnames like '%~%'
```

Note with limited info that you have provied,  this is not the most efficient way as it will be scanning the table.